# Relationship Metadata in Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Is there a way to fetch relationship description in dynamics crm through C# ?

I have looked into OnetoManyMetadata object but could not find it anywhere.

Comment: Show us your code what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveentityrequest.aspx

```
var cl = new CrmServiceClient(...);
var q = new RetrieveEntityRequest { 
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Relationships, 
    LogicalName = "..." 
};
var r = (cl.Execute(q) as RetrieveEntityResponse).EntityMetadata;
var OtM = r.OneToManyRelationships;
var MtM = r.ManyToManyRelationships;
var MtO = r.ManyToOneRelationships;
```